# Why isn't my div at the top of the page?

Tags: html, css

I'm making a webpage, but I can't seem to get my header div at the very top of the page. There is always a little gap above it. I've tried looking around, but all the solutions of tried don't work.

[The webpage in progress](http://thegrits.github.io/)

```css
#body {
    margin: 0 !important; <!--I thought these "importants" would fix it -->
    padding: 0 !important;
}

#header {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 80px;
    width: auto;
    background-color: #3385FF;
    font-family: 'Cabin', serif;
    font-size: 60px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cabin:400,600' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<body>
    <div id="header"><p id="header_text">The_Grits</p></div> <!-- This is the div I want at the top of the page. -->
</body>
```

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: The problem has been answered now, thanks for looking anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove the id selector from **body** and remove the margin applied to the **paragraph** element.

Remove the user agent default margin applied to the <**p**> element and the <**body**> adding this code:

```
      body, p {
        margin: 0; 
      }

      #header {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        height: 80px;
        width: auto;
        background-color: #3385FF;
        font-family: 'Cabin', serif;
        font-size: 60px;
        text-align: center;
      }
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll accept your answer because you replied before the other two.

Answer (score 1):

Your paragraph `p` has default margin, because you have missed to add `_text` in your css rule `#header`.

Try this snippet:

```css
#body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#header_text {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 80px;
  width: auto;
  background-color: #3385FF;
  font-family: 'Cabin', serif;
  font-size: 60px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
 <div id="header">
   <p id="header_text">The_Grits</p>
</div>
```

Comment: When you find yourself using !important on such a basic page, something is wrong with the way you're thinking about your CSS.

Comment: I just copied the OP code, and pointed out where is his mistake :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `#body` matches the element with `id` set to `body`, you don't have such elements so it's completely redundant (it should be just `body`).
Secondly, "The_Grits" is within `p`, which adds its own margin. Add

```
#header_text { margin: 0 }
```

to your CSS.

See the demo:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cabin:400,600' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <!--Above imports the font I'm using-->
    <title>The_Grits Programming</title>
    <style>
      body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      
      #header_text { margin: 0 }

      #header {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        height: 80px;
        width: auto;
        background-color: #3385FF;
        font-family: 'Cabin', serif;
        font-size: 60px;
        text-align: center;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="header"><p id="header_text">The_Grits</p></div> <!-- This is the div I want at the top of the page. -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you, your answer along with @Alessandro Incarnati 's helped me fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

because you have to add: `p {margin:0px;}` or add the `#header_text { margin:0px }`

When you create a new style sheet, try to reset all element's `padding` and `margin` to `0px`. This would help you.

http://jsfiddle.net/bpmck3wt/

Answer (score 0):

```
 #header {
    display:block;
    position:absoulute;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    left:0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 80px;
    background-color: #3385FF;
    font-family: 'Cabin', serif;
    font-size: 60px;
    text-align: center;
  }
```

why don't you specify the position and the dispaly ?